# How do I disassemble a Python script from the command line?

Tags: python, bytecode

With gcc you can use -S to stop compilation after your code has been compiled into assembly. Is there a similar feature with Python/bytecode? I know of ways like:

```
import dis
x = compile('print(1)', '', 'eval')
dis.dis(x)
```

Which prints:

```
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (print)
              2 LOAD_CONST               0 (1)
              4 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              6 RETURN_VALUE
```

But I'm thinking of something more along the lines of:

```
> python3 -{SOME FLAG HERE} output my_script.py
```

Which outputs a file containing the scripts bytecode in a readable format.

Comment: "Which outputs a file containing the scripts bytecode in a readable format." so then you *don't* want the scripts bytecode, you want the output of the dissasembler? Because the bytecode is just bytes...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thank you for clearing up the semantics for me, but yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If what you are looking for is the output of the *disassembler*, then you can run the module as a script:

```
python -m dis myscript.py
```

And the disassembler output will be printed to the standard output. You can use the appropriate shell tools to redirect that to some file. E.g. on *nix:

```
python -m dis myscript.py > output.txt
```

Caution: this use of `dis` is not documented as far as I am aware, and checking the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c5bfb88eb6f82111bb1603ae9d78d0476b552d66/Lib/dis.py#L527) it may not be a stable part of the module, but it *does* work for current CPython.